# Не работает count(*)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

По неизвестным мне причинам не могу вывести количество заказов.
Вместо числа просто пустота. В чем может быть причина?

```
/* Посылаем запрос серверу */ 
if ($result_orders = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) FROM `orders`")) { 

    /* Выборка результатов запроса */ 
    while( $row_orders = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_orders) ){ 
        echo "Кол-во заказов: ".$row_orders[0].".<br>";
    } 

    /* Освобождаем используемую память */ 
    mysqli_free_result($result_orders); 
} 

/* Закрываем соединение */ 
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: массив же не нумерованный `print_r($row_orders)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ключом массива в данном случае будет `COUNT(*)` (`$row_orders['COUNT(*)']`, а не `$row_orders[0]`).

Лучше присвойте псевдоним (алиас) столбца `count(*) as count_rows` (*count_rows для примера*) и будет работать ([статья](http://aktual.com.ua/all/mysql-psevdonimy-bystro-prosto-legko/)).

```
/* Посылаем запрос серверу */ 
if ($result_orders = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) as count_rows FROM `orders`")) { 
    /* Выборка результатов запроса */ 
    while( $row_orders = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_orders) ){ 
        echo "Кол-во заказов: ".$row_orders['count_rows'].".<br>";
    } 
    /* Освобождаем используемую память */ 
    mysqli_free_result($result_orders); 
} 

/* Закрываем соединение */ 
mysqli_close($link);
```